# VSCode Settings: Python > Data Science category missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I love VSCode, and one of my favorite features randomly disappeared this week with the new version of VSCode. In Settings, under Python, there used to be a "Data Science" category where I could turn on "Python > Data Science: Send Selection To Interactive Window". This is no longer an option for me, and the Data Science category is completely missing for me. Does anyone know how to turn this feature back on?

Helpful information:

- I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Python extension; it's currently on version 2020.11.358366026
- My default language is set to Python
- My interpretter is Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('base': conda)
- I can right click and "Run Current File in Interactive Window" but not highlight specific rows like I could before to run them in python interactive.

Comment: A makeshift solution to bypass this problem is to downgrade your version of VS Code to earlier ones. In my case, there is nothing wrong with the Python extension, and after I installed version 1.47.3, the data science section under the Python category in the setting comes back.

Answer (score -1):

**Note that:**

- There could be any of the one or many reasons why data science catagory is missing in VS-Code.
- These type of issues can be resolved just by updating,adding or changing enviourments, settings or variables.

So, ultimately trying all of these methods will surely resolve your issue.

**Option 1: Update Python Extension.**

Do you have the latest version of the Python extension for VSCode. If latest doesn't work out, try the version of before 2020.11.358366026.

**Option 2: Check Python Interpreter**

Verify that you have the correct Python interpreter selected in VSCode. Confirm that this interpreter is still available and correctly configured.

**Option 3: Reset VSCode Settings**

Sometimes, settings issues can be resolved by resetting VSCode settings to their default values.

**Option 4: Check Python Extension Settings**

Ensure that the Python extension settings are correctly configured and

- `"python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow"` is set to `true`.

**Option 5: Reinstall Python Extension (if necessary)**

If the issue persists after trying the above steps, you can try a more thorough re-installation of the Python extension.

**Option 6: Restart VSCode**

After making any changes or reinstalling the extension, it's essential to restart VSCode to ensure that the changes take effect. Sometime just a restart resolves the issue without any settings.

**Option 7: Check for Updates in VSCode**

Have you made sure that you are using the latest version of Visual Studio Code itself. Sometimes, updating the code editor can resolve compatibility issues with extensions.

**Option 8: Verify Extension Compatibility**

Check the Python extension's release notes or documentation to ensure that the "Data Science" category and the specific feature you're looking for are still supported and haven't been deprecated.

**If still not resloved:**

If the problem persists, consider checking the Python extension's GitHub repository / community forums.

Hope it helps.